# Can I develop a WordPress site without a domain?

Tags: customization, development-strategy

I currently have a wix.com website and want to make the switch to WordPress. I'm really confused about how I do this or whether I can?

But in the meantime, I want to start building my site (as I am re-branding) on WordPress and then hopefully I can just connect it to the domain I have with wix.com (once I've figured out how to transfer it to another host).

Is this possible? If so, any help would be great. As front-end visuals of a website I can do, but the back-end stuff is a little alien to me.

Comment: It's also worth noting that some hosts will give you a temporary domain while you're working on your site. You can use this until you have a permanent domain for your site.

Answer (score 2):

This question actually is a bit too broad. As it would mean to explain you how to develop and deploy a site on your local computer. Which is a pretty opinion-based thing. And which additionally isn't specific to WordPress.

But you could simply start to follow this Codex tutorial: [Installing WordPress Locally on Your Mac With MAMP](https://codex.wordpress.org/Installing_WordPress_Locally_on_Your_Mac_With_MAMP) or this MAMP tutorial: [MAMP (Windows) Documentation > How Tos > WordPress](https://documentation.mamp.info/en/MAMP-Windows/How-Tos/WordPress/). Then develop your site.

When you are done you need to upload every single file to a web server via FTP for example. Also you need to dump your local database and import that on your server.

Comment: There are some more generic options (ie, if you don't have a Mac) available here: [Installing WordPress on your own Computer](https://wordpress.org/support/article/installing-wordpress-on-your-own-computer/)